# Got error when plotting two different curves of two functions in R

Tags: r

`a<-function(x) exp(-x)
 b<-function(x) 0.75*exp(-0.75*x)
 plot(a,xlim=c(-3,3),type="l",col="red3",lwd=2)
 lines(b,xlim=c(-3,3),type="l",col="blue3")`

I want to draw these two functions' graph in one axis, but an error shows:
Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

How to fix this?

Comment: I think you are confusing `xlim` with `function(x)`...

Comment: For plotting you have to provide actual values, not only the function used to produce the values. You could for instance use `plot(a(c(1:10)), ... )`

Comment: Thanks but no, when I just use the first plot(...) function it can conduct a graph, the problem is about the function lines(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a<-function(x) exp(-x)
b<-function(x) 0.75*exp(-0.75*x)

plot(a,xlim=c(-3,3),type="l",col="red3",lwd=2)
plot(b,xlim=c(-3,3),type="l",col="blue3", add = TRUE)
```

use `plot()` instead of `lines()` and add the `add = TRUE` parameter

[image]

EDIT: But I'd suggest using ggplot for graphics. This code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-3,3)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun=a, geom="line", aes(colour="Function a: exp(-x)")) +
  stat_function(fun=b, geom="line", aes(colour="Function b: 0.75*exp(-0.75*x)")) +
  labs(colour = "Functions")
```

will give you this nice image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach utilizing the function curve which draws a curve corresponding to a function over the interval defined by `from` and `to`.

```
a <- function(x) exp(-x)
b <- function(x) 0.75*exp(-0.75*x)
plot(a, xlim = c(-3, 3), type = "l",col = "red3", lwd = 2)
curve(b, from = -3, to = 3, col = "blue3", add = T, lwd = 2)
legend("topright", c("a", "b"), col = c("red3", "blue3"), lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

the call to `plot` is in fact a call to `plot.function` a S3 method for class `function` since the first argument is a function. If one types  `?plot.function` the documentation calls `curve {graphics}`.

equivalent approaches are:

```
curve(a, from = -3, to = 3, col = "red3", lwd = 2)
curve(b, from = -3, to = 3, col = "blue3", add = T, lwd = 2)
legend("topright", c("a", "b"), col = c("red3", "blue3"), lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

and

```
plot(a, xlim = c(-3, 3), type = "l",col = "red3", lwd = 2)
plot(b, xlim = c(-3, 3), type = "l",col = "blue3", lwd = 2, add = T)
legend("topright", c("a", "b"), col = c("red3", "blue3"), lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

since they all call `curve`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this tomorrow.